# matplotlib 3d-plot of combinations of x and z intervals

Tags: python-3.x, list, matplotlib, 3d

I'd like to plot a funktion like this: f(x, z) = x/z where `x = z = list(range(, 10)` with all combinations of x and z. I tried:

```
def f(X, Y):
    return X/Y

def data(r=10):
    X = [i/10 for i in range(0, r)]
    Y = X.copy()
    x, y = zip(*[[e, i] for e in Y for i in X])
    z = [f(x[i], y[i]) if y[i] else float('Nan') for i in range(len(x))]
    return x, y, z
```

so I get x, y, and z data. Am I able to plot a 3d plot with this 3 lists now? I only found solutions working with numpy-arrays...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`trisurf`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#tri-surface-plots) with your 1d lists

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Your functions here

x, y, z = data(r=10)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! Is there a way to plot the lines without a surface?

Comment: You can use [wire3d](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/wire3d.html) by converting your data to 2d arrays